# Repeating a subject twice - a matter of style or grammar?

Tags: writing-style, conjunction-reduction, compound-predicates

Is repeating the subject twice in a sentence considered a grammar error or bad style? For example:

> Epic Game Music will be held for the first time in Poland at Poznan
>   Game Arena and Game Industry Conference 2018 and **it is** planned as a
>   powerful and emotional opening event for...

or maybe the subject should be omitted and the sentence should go like this

> Epic Game Music will be held for the first time in Poland at Poznan
>   Game Arena and Game Industry Conference 2018 and **is** planned as a
>   powerful and emotional opening event for

Which way is more correct and sounds better to your ear?

Comment: It's just a stylistic choice. But one factor you should take into account is that the more intervening text you have between the *first* use of the relevant noun and the subsequent "back-reference" to it, the harder it is for the reader to parse your text. For your specific example, explicitly including ***it*** as a "placeholder" for ***Epic Game Music*** isn't particularly necessary in that respect. Include it or don't, whatever feels "reasonable" to you.

Comment: Thank you for your very informative comment, FumbleFingers!

Comment: @FumbleFingers You should write more answers, Fumbelina. :)

Answer (score 1):

In a comment, FumbleFingers wrote:

> It's just a stylistic choice. But one factor you should take into account is that the more intervening text you have between the *first* use of the relevant noun and the subsequent "back-reference" to it, the harder it is for the reader to parse your text. For your specific example, explicitly including ***it*** as a "placeholder" for ***Epic Game Music*** isn't particularly necessary in that respect. Include it or don't, whatever feels "reasonable" to you.

Comment: [Related](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/614851/2085).